# How to get client side generated class list to MVC post action argument?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have one form where I am generating some control dynamically (Which is list some  class . in image add product artwork section) When I click on submit button how can i get this values in post Action method's argument so that I can use this value in collection.

For reference I have attached the image where i have option for multiple Artwork oprion [image]

```
[HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Add(Graphic graphicToAdd,Enumerable<GraphicArtwork> artworkOption)
{
// I want value in artworkOption 
}

public class GraphicArtwork
    {
        [Key]
        public int GraphicArtworkId { get; set; }
        public int GraphisId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} is required.")]
        [DisplayName("Option Text")]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string ArtOptionText { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Active")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int TotalRecordCount { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my view :

```
<div class="editor-field PrintOptions">            
            <table data-bind="visible :customArtworks().length > 0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="editor-label">Option</td>
                        <td class="editor-label">Price</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: customArtworks">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input placeholder="Enter Artwork Text" type="text" data-bind="value: ArtOptionText'}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input placeholder="Enter Price" type="text" data-bind="value: Price" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.add"><img title="Add" src="~/Content/images/icon_add.png"></a>
                            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.remove,visible: $root.customArtworks().length > 1"><img title="Delete" style="margin-left:10px;" src="~/Content/images/icon_delete.png"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

For more detail :  I am generating my dynamical control using knockout.js

```
 // Ko Implemntation

        function GraphicArtwork(ArtOptionText, Price) {
            var self = this;
            self.ArtOptionText = ArtOptionText;
            self.Price = Price;

            self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function () {
                var price = self.Price;
                return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "0.00";
            })

        }

        function GraphicArtworkViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.customArtworks = ko.observableArray([GraphicArtwork(null, null)]);

            self.add = function () {
                self.customArtworks.push(new GraphicArtwork(null, null));
            };

            self.remove = function (GraphicArtwork) {
                self.customArtworks.remove(GraphicArtwork);
            };

        }

        ko.applyBindings(new GraphicArtworkViewModel());
```

Comment: You need to show the relevant code including the models and how you are generating the controls for properties of the model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke check the updated question.

Comment: You're not showing how you're generating the controls you're showing how your binding your knockout view models. Need to see the html with your binding syntax etc. In particular everything inside your POST form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add This binding :

```
<td>
                            <input placeholder="Enter Artwork Text" type="text" data-bind="value: ArtOptionText,attr:{name: '['+$index()+'].ArtOptionText'}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input placeholder="Enter Price" type="text" data-bind="value: Price,attr:{name: '['+$index()+'].Price'}" />
                        </td>
```

AND in Code Behind

```
public ActionResult Add(Graphic graphicToAdd,IEnumerable<GraphicArtwork> listOfGraphicArtwork)
{
 // listOfGraphicArtwork will hold all the required data 
}
```